# create pairs of tops from the number of paths from the top, create a continuous graph, just one option

Tags: python, graph-theory

In Python, I have list of sums of path from tops : graph theory
I would like to create pairs to represent the edges of a single graph.

I have list coming from a source as:
another example

```
list = [1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4]
```

I need to convert it into pairs or edges between tops of the  one single graph. Just create one option.
if it cannot be created one single graph from the input, it prints an error

```
output = [[1,3],[2,3],[3,5],[4,5],[5,6],[5,7],[7,8]]
```

graph:

```
1--3--2
   |
4--5--6
   |
   7
   |
   8
```

another example:

```
input = [1,1,1,2,3]
```

graph :

```
5--3--4
   |
   2
   |
   1
```

```
output = [[5,3],[3,4], [3,2],[1,2]]
```

What is the best way to go about this??

Comment: What research have you done ?

Comment: I want to use graph theory to solve this problem but i don't find any solutions.

Comment: [how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)